# Why cmap='Greys' does not do anything for a colored image?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Why simply changing the color map does not convert a colored image to black and white?

```
img = imread('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1257/7487/articles/bee-flower_1024x.jpg?v=1585344606')
plt.imshow(img, cmap='Greys')

plt.colorbar()
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Explanation

`img` is an array-like data structure. It has size `(M,N,3)` where `M` and `N` are the side lengths of the original image, in pixels. This means that the data is formatted as RGB values. According to the matplotlib documentation, the `cmap` parameter of `plt.imshow(...)` is ignored if the input array is in RBG or RBGA format.

Link to documentation: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow